# Silverlight: Access client desktop- Display properties

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asp.net-3.5, silverlight-2.0

I want to access the display properties of the client desktop in silverlight application and modify the application layout according 2 the ones set on client machine.  When we right click on desktop and choose properties we get display properties dialog. i want to access appearance and theme properties from this. i hv to retrieve the appearance properties like font, theme etc and apply them in my silverlight application. I am also not sure whether this can be done in a normal web application.

Tried to google it but could find anything except code for resizing. But I want to access not only the screen width and height but the appearance settings also.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No way. This is private data that should not be exposed to any other domains.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to Silverlight, but check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541468/how-do-i-match-my-controls-styles-to-the-current-theme-wpf/543866#543866) regarding different styles based on the current windows theme.

As far as the width/height, unless your running your silverlight app in fullscreen, what should be more important is the browser window width/height as that will not always be the same size as the screen itself. You should be able to google for code for how to get the browser window width/height rather easily.

Answer (score 0):

The Silverlight sandbox prevents access to the client machine. You could try using a ActiveX control to expose the data to the silverlight control or you could use a WPF browser app with elevated trust permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` to get height and width, and send those values as startup params to `silverlight` application.