# WPF Change control's background to system color

Tags: wpf

I want to make the background color of a grid the same as the system color.

And when user change system color (by choosing another color in Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Personalization > Window Color and Appearance) 
I also want the background color of the grid reflect the change I made.

So here is my XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}">
            </SolidColorBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But the grid appears in white.

And when I change the system color, nothing changes.

Comment: This link might be helpful for you! write theme files in resource dictionary with the brushes given! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541468/how-do-i-match-my-controls-styles-to-the-current-theme-wpf

Comment: The `WindowColor` is white. Try another BrushKey, i.e.; `<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}">`

Comment: I want the background color of my grid to be the same as the background color of the title bar. Can you guys tell me what is the key of the resource needed?